# Can 301 redirects be used to consolidate three domains into one?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, 301-redirect

I'm managing the website of an online shop. It has 3 domains. We are  planning to migrate to using just one domain as soon as possible.  The other 2 domains will be deleted.

If I access the other two domains, I think it would be best to 301 redirect while looking for a way to connect to the domain I actually use.

1. Can a 301 rrdirect be used if only one of the three domains is left and two are deleted?
2. If it is not available, what is the other solution?

Comment: If you want to delete the rest of the domain, no index both.
If you want to use 301 you need the domain.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't "delete" domains. It's unclear what you mean.
2. 301s won't work if you "delete" domains. Domains have to be registered ans hooked to some hosting (even if only to the domain zone hosting like cloudflare, but then that wouldn't be a 301 redirect, that would be a CNAME mapping).
3. To do what you intend, you need to keep all the domains maintained. The server-side redirection happens on the hosting level, not on the domain level. Every domain would have an associated server managing the server responses to the clients. The config of that server decides whether to respond with a 301 or anything else.
4. You set up your redirection rules in your web-server config. Typically, it's htaccess since Apache is popular among small sites.
5. Finally, yes, it is possible to redirect any amount of domains to any amount of domains except that you don't really redirect domains. You redirect urls. And you don't redirect to domains, you redirect to urls. To redirect all urls of a domain, you can use basic regular expressions when using Apache's [mod rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Said that, while it's intuitively expedient to make a redirection from all pages of domain A to the home page of domain B, that is typically a lazy solution that results in poor authority transition and often poor user experience. You want to map old urls to new urls pretty much one to one, given that the structure and the topic are similar.

One more thing, contrary to a popular misconception, redirecting a page to another page will almost never result in the recipient page to maintain the sum of organic traffic of both pages long-term. Same is even more true for whole domains of pages. In other words, if you have three domains in one niche and each gets 10k organic traffic per month, and you decide to redirect two domains to one, you will likely see close to 30k organic traffic on that domain for some time, but then it will begin dwindle to, depending on a situation, about 12k-15k. That is Google realizing there's no point to rank pages that are not 301. So in cases where all three domains would take positions for one search query, there will now be only one domain.

There's also a grey SEO technique when people purchase expired domains that are still linked to from valuable sources and redirect those domains to the recipient domain. While it sounds simple, there are many many caveats and a quite a powerful competition with a lot of automation onboard.

Senior technical SEOs do the opposite from what you try to do: once the client's main keywords and long tail are in a good spot of growth, they would go for making separate sites in the same niche to target the same keywords more than once. If getting your page rank #1 would give you about 25% of search volume (heavily depends on niche), ranking #2 would bring 15%, and ranking #3 would bring 10% , then ranking for all three positions will yield you half of the search volume. And if you're good enough to push rich snippets, that may bring your yield close to three quarters.